# remove commits from a feature branch

Tags: git, github

I was working on a feature branch and committed my changes to create a pull request on a remote rep. The PR was approved I only needed to fix some styles for a build to run successfully. When I finished and was ready to merge my branch with master, one file from my commits was changed and Git asked to resolve a conflict. So I merged master into my feature branch on GitHub and it ended up moving all previous commits into that branch. It caused the build to fail and I also have a bunch of uncommitted files in my local repo.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you saying, you don't want the master branch changes in your feature branch and it lead to build failure? If you don't take master branch code to your feature branch, even then while deploying both your changes and master changes will be in same branch. So build failure issue can come there as well, right?

Comment: yes, that is strange to me but when I run 'lerna run build-tsc' on local now it shows many TypeScript errors in my local repo. Very weird

Comment: @SANGEETHKUMARSG I actually didn't expect that resolving conflict in one file will cause merging all the commits from master to my feature branch

Comment: git merge by branch works in that way. It merges all the commits the remote branch to your branch when you do `git pull origin master`. Or you can rebase your branch with the master branch. Which will do the same thing, but it will write your commits on top of the master branch commits. But in that flow also both branch commits will be together.

Comment: @SANGEETH KUMAR S G is there a way to rollback or what else should I do to fix that?

Comment: `git reset HEAD~1` this command will revert the last commit and put everything in staged changes. But the conflict you resolved will also get reverted.

Comment: @SANGEETH KUMAR S G I did that but it still show that bunch of untracted files in my local rep

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223867/discussion-between-sangeeth-kumar-s-g-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `git pull origin master --rebase`. This will put your changes on top of the master branch changes. But still it you will be having both branch changes.

You can revert the last commit by `git reset HEAD~1`. This command will revert last commit and put everything in staged changes.

Comment: Without `--soft`, they won't be "staged", they'll be "unstaged".